# Calling async function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I have an async function

```
async function getPostAsync() {
  const post = await Post.findById('id');

  // if promise was successful,
  // but post with specific id doesn't exist
  if (!post) {
    throw new Error('Post was not found');
  }

  return post;
}
```

I am calling the function with

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  getPostAsync().then(post => {
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      err
    });
  })
});
```

but I just receive

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "err": {}
}
```

I would expect to either get the error `Post was not found` or some error with the connection or something like that, but the variable `err` is simply an empty object in my `catch` statement.

Comment: does `Post.findById` return a Promise?

Comment: Yes it does. It is from `mongoose`

Comment: Try to send full error object in your catch block: `err: JSON.stringify(err)`, it's possible that error object doesn't contain a message, because of that `err` is empty string in a response.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(post)` just before returning it  in your `getPostAsync()` function ?

Comment: I have figured out that the model `Post` was not imported. It should have failed with something like `Post is undefined`. How can I make sure I get those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
let e = Error('foobar');
console.log( JSON.stringify(e) )
```

This outputs `{}`, much like in your case. That's because errors don't serialize to JSON very well.

Instead, try this:

```
res.status(400).json({
  status : 'error',
  err    : err.message // `String(err)` would also work
});
```